# Loading NSData into WKWebview shows doc and XLS file in some encoded format

Tags: ios, nsdata, wkwebview, local-files

I have a requirement where I need to load NSData (from a local file like doc or xls) into `WKWebView`.

Loading a file URL works fine but converting into data and the loading it using loadData shows xls and doc files in some encoded format.Converting file into

```
NSData using - [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.fileURLPath];
```

and loading data into wkwebview using

`[self.webView loadData:data MIMEType:self.MIMEType characterEncodingName:@""  baseURL:self.fileURL.NSURL];`

Observations -
Works fine with `UIWebView` and also when loading fileurl directly into `WKWebView`.